# Usage of 'the' with an adjective in superlative degree when there is no noun

Tags: usage

Should I put 'the' before an adjective in superlative degree when there is no noun.

For example:

```
I am (the) strongest.
You are (the) best.
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: Add the implied noun and check again. Would you choose "I am strongest man"? I wouldn't.

Comment: If you put an article in front, it's becomes like a noun.  So you can put a "the" or not, it just depends on how you want to phrase your sentence.